# Unable to pass checkmarx security review

Tags: apex, with-sharing, without-sharing

When I use 'Without Sharing' Keyword with class  in a managed package and install it in a destination org or sandbox, the code works fine but get error in the checkmarx report.
If I replace 'without' with 'with' keyword checkmarx report do not show any error but code does not work in the managed package.
What should i do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is intended to run as an automation (e.g. a trigger), it may be acceptable to mark the class as "without sharing;" you just need to explain the rationale in your exceptions/false positives report when submitting your app to the Security Review. Otherwise, if this code must have security enabled, you'll have to fix it such that it works with security enabled. This may mean making appropriate checks using describe calls to verify the user can access the objects, fields, and records that are being used, and display an appropriate error message if they do not have access.